# iPhone 4s is not connecting properly with Xcode 4.0?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to connect iPhone 4S with XCode 4.0, but iPhone 4s is not working with XCode 4.0.

Any Solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not your iPhone problem. There is a bug in Xcode4.0 So try it with Xcode 3.2 or Xcode 4.1 or so on...

All The best!!

Comment: you can also installed iphone configuration utility for install directly IPA.